# C# class to byte stream

Tags: c#

What is the correct way to convert my class to/from a byte array? I want to be able to do thing like save it to a file as simply as possible.

Should I make it serializable?
Should I just supply a function that returns a byte array? Or maybe a MemoryStream?
Something else?

I am not overly familiar with C# file handling, so if the answer could also show what the common way of writing binary data to a file is, I would appreciate it.

**Edit** I see from the answers that I am misunderstood. I have a class. I have a format I want to save it in binary form in. I want to know what the correct way is to expose this binary representation. I need full control of the format, not .NET doing it for me (I will be reading it later in c++)

Comment: Google "binary serialization" in .NET. Simple reference matter.

Comment: @baunch: if you need a full control a `protobuf` (mantioned in my answer) in one of possible choices definitely.

Comment: @Tigran to clarify: protobuf doesn't provide "full control", but it is very definitely portable between C# and C++.

Comment: @MarcGravell: ok, but the "full control" means, basically, write something from stratch. Here I mean "flexible enough".

Comment: @Tigran then I entirely agree; something portable like protobuf would save baruch a vast amount of time and bugs.

Comment: @MarcGravell: in modern times there is *really* small probability that  someone will need to write a `serializator` from stratch. There are a lot of stuff is already done out there, so basically we pick "ready to run" solution. That's why I didn't even consider a case of writing something custom.

Comment: @Tigran some crazy idiot still needs to write/port the library though (looks around nervously...)

Comment: @MarcGravell: :) I said "small probability". There will be always cases where we need this, but this question doesn't seem to me a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your edit, and given the fact that you own the binary format and need to control it yourself, I see two options:

- a method that accepts a stream and writes the binary representation to the stream
- a method that returns a byte array

Of course, you could decouple this from the type itself by creating another class with

- a method that accepts an instance of your type and a stream and writes the binary representation to the stream
- a method that accepts an instance of your type and returns a byte array

The first option of each pair probably gives you more flexibility; you could pass a file stream or a memory stream or whatnot depending on your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), it's easy to understand and begin to code to see the result immediately. But after, naturally, read different articles on subject to choice a best match for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

In order of preference:

1) If your application is database-aware, then store data you wish to "remember" to a database.

2) A simple flat file or XML file (i.e. "don't serialize: just save state")

3) Otherwise, serialization is probably what you're looking for

Here's a link on .Net serialization:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

Here's a link on serializing to XML (instead of binary):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

```
using System;

public class clsPerson
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

class class1
{ 
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      clsPerson p=new clsPerson();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(p.GetType());
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, p);
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Again - I strongly recommend "serialization" as a last resort (just "save state" as simply and robustly as possible, if possible), and "binary serialization" as a VERY last resort (unless you have a very good reason for doing otherwise).

IMHO...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "save state" using a flat file? I don't understand the difference between that and binary serilization.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). Note that your class must be [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) for this to work.

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(object source)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);                
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Writing crucial data to the disk as TEXT is always dangerous. Any anonymous user can open the text file and easily read your data. With Object Serialization, you can reduce this danger to a certain extent. You can write any complex object directly to a **filestream** without converting values of individual properties into a text. You can make the data written, to the disk, atleast not human readable. In order for the users to read your data files, they have to use your program. Like a File Open command which you may provide in your application.
>
> **Serialization** is the process of converting complex objects into stream of bytes for storage. **Deserialization** is its reverse process, that is unpacking stream of bytes to their original form. The namespace which is used to read and write files is System.IO. For Serialization we are going to look at the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace. The **ISerializable** interface allows you to make any class Serializable. [See](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx) with good examples.

---

> As mentioned above, *serialization* is the process of converting an
>   object into a stream of bytes in order to persist it to memory, a
>   database, or a file. Its main purpose is to save the state of an
>   object in order to be able to recreate it when needed. The reverse
>   process is called *deserialization*.
>
> **How Serialization Works**
>
> The following illustration shows the overall process of serialization.
>
> [image]
>
> The object is serialized to a stream, which carries not just the data,
>   but information about the object's type, such as its version, culture,
>   and assembly name. From that stream, it can be stored in a database, a
>   file, or memory. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

if you mean how you can serialize a class using a Binary serialization you can have a look at the code below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace BinarySerializationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Serialization of String Object   

            String writeData = "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0";
            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream("C:\\StringObject.data", FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(writeStream, writeData);
            writeStream.Close();

            // Deserialization of String Object

            FileStream readStream = new FileStream("C:\\StringObject.data", FileMode.Open);
            String readData = (String) formatter.Deserialize(readStream);
            readStream.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(readData);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example I serialize a string but you can serialize "any object". All you need to do is add the attribute `[Serializable]` on your class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Car
{
    public string Make;
    public string Model;

}
```

if you want to implement a custom serialization your class needs to implement the `ISerializable` interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182342(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: I want to be able to serialize my class, and I want to have control of the serialized format.

Comment: you can serialize your class using an XML format or a Binary Format.